# What network interface does a packet get to when it is routed to the IP of the machine itself?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, routing, ping

I configured my machine like so:

```
eth0 - 192.168.70.128/24, default gw 192.168.70.128
```

When trying to send an ICMP request, for example, such that it would route through the default gateway, I get an ICMP Unreachable Host error:

```
From 192.168.70.128 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
```

which makes sense.

Looking at the traffic capture, I can see that ICMP Unreachable packet on the loopback interface:

```
5   3.072955110 192.168.70.128  192.168.70.128  ICMP    128 Destination unreachable (Host unreachable)
```

Of course, the ICMP unreachable message contains the packet that was not able to get sent to its destination:

```
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.70.128, Dst: 8.8.8.8
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
    Total Length: 84
    Identification: 0x3b84 (15236)
    Flags: 0x40, Don't fragment
    ...0 0000 0000 0000 = Fragment Offset: 0
    Time to Live: 64
    Protocol: ICMP (1)
    Header Checksum: 0xe7ec [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
    Source Address: 192.168.70.128
    Destination Address: 8.8.8.8
Internet Control Message Protocol
    Type: 8 (Echo (ping) request)
    Code: 0
    Checksum: 0x7a29 [unverified] [in ICMP error packet]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    Identifier (BE): 25938 (0x6552)
    Identifier (LE): 21093 (0x5265)
    Sequence Number (BE): 1 (0x0001)
    Sequence Number (LE): 256 (0x0100)
    Timestamp from icmp data: May  5, 2022 12:15:36.000000000 EDT
    [Timestamp from icmp data (relative): 3.291527300 seconds]
    Data (48 bytes)
```

What I am missing is the original packet - it is not captured on any of the interfaces present in my machine, so where did it go? And how can I capture it as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying yourself as the gateway has the meaning of creating an *on-link* route, the same as if no gateway was specified. (It's unusual on Linux, but I think this comes from BSD.)

In other words, your `0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.70.128` works like `0.0.0.0/0 dev eth0`, and indicates that the *entire* 0.0.0.0/0 is a "local subnet" where the destination IP address must be resolved via ARP and the packet sent directly to the destination host's MAC address (instead of a gateway's MAC as would be the case with a normal "gateway" route).

So the reason you are not seeing the outgoing ICMP packets on eth0 is because they cannot be sent *yet*, until the OS knows what next-hop MAC address to send them to – it has to successfully make an ARP lookup first. In this case, Linux will be sending out ARP queries for `8.8.8.8` on the eth0 interface. (This is also the case for regular "gateway" routes, except for them it's the gateway IP address that needs to be resolved via ARP.)

The error "Destination **Host** Unreachable" means that no ARP reply arrived for the final host, exactly the same as if you had simply tried to ping a nonexistent IP address within your subnet.

---

(But this is not an unreasonable configuration in general – at least in the past, some networks *used to* configure all their hosts to assume the entire 0.0.0.0/0 was local, and the gateways would respond on behalf of every host, i.e. "proxy ARP". This had several purposes – hosts didn't need to know the gateway's address, and there could be several gateways handling different destinations without hosts needing to know exact routes.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! It does seem to be acting the exact same way with a nonexistent host in the same subnet. What's the explanation for the ICMP request packet showing up in the "Destination Host Unreachable" ICMP message? I'm guessing the OS has put it there since it knows what was supposed to be sent

Comment: The "original packet" payload is mandatory for ICMP errors. But it always starts at the IP layer headers (which is _always_ known if we got to the point where an ICMP error could be triggered) and doesn't include the MAC layer header (which is the unknown part in our case), so the OS can include it even in situations like these.